# Copy data from all files in a folder

Tags: excel, directory, copy-paste, vba

I need to open all Excel files that are in a folder, and copy every first, 57th, 72th, 73th and 74th row from each file into the same workbook.

This this is what I have so far:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
MyPath = "C:\foldername" 'the folder
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls") 'all excel files in folder

Do Until strFilename = ""

    'here it gives an error, saying it can't open file,
    ' even though it apparently has found it
    wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strFilename)

    'copy relevant text
    Workbooks(2).Activate
    Sheets("blad1").Rows(1, 57, 72, 73, 74).Copy
    Workbooks(1).Activate
    'select the first empty row
    irow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    'insert the copied
    irow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'close the workbook without saving
    Workbooks(2).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Close

Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
MyPath = "C:\foldername" 'the folder
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls") 'all excel files in folder

Do Until strFilename = ""
...
strFilename=Dir()
Loop
```

Tell me if this works

EDIT: Fix `Sheets("blad1").Rows(1, 57, 72, 73, 74).Copy` to
`Sheets("blad1").Rows("1, 57, 72, 73, 74").Copy`

Comment: No, still isn't working. Strangely, it keeps giving this error: "(correct file name.xls) cannot be found." for line Workbooks.Open (strFilename)

Comment: Well, i've tried the following:
strFilename = Dir()
Workbooks.Open (MyPath & "\" & strFilename)
'rest is same

which opens the first file, but then says the file isnt truly an xls file, and stops..

Comment: I'm getting the same error as before.  The issue might be that when i try to open the workbook manually, I also get the same msg: "file does not have the same file format as its extension. Perhaps it's from an unreliable source blabla, are you sure you want to open it?"

Comment: jep, that does seem to work. (THANKS!) 

However, how I was planning to copy and paste the rows apparently doesn't work either. lol.

Bigger issue: is there a way to workaround the so-called corrupted (but perfectly working) files?

Comment: @Asad - The message you're seeing is most likely due to "content hardening" - see here: http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/08/11/Excel-Extension-Hardening-and-Web-Applications.aspx

Comment: It says "wrong number of arguments" and points to the row in which I define the rows to copy (Sheets("Blad1").Rows(1, 57, 72, 73, 74).Copy)